# Imploying a sequence in a series

Tags: series-expansion, summation, sequence

I would like to have the following sequence, $(a)_n$, in a series where
$a_0 = 1$ and $a_n = a(a+1)\cdots (a+ n -1)$. The series I have is
$$
2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1/2)_n}{n!(2n+1)^3}
$$
I know how to represent series in mathematica but I have no idea how I can insert the sequence into the series code. What I have is

```
2 Sum[Sequence Here/(n!(2n+1)^3),{n,0,infinity}]
```

Is it possible to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Are you looking for *Pochhammer* perhaps?

Comment: @rasher yes, that worked. Should I delete or do you want provide an answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll answer... future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after *Pochhammer*:

```
Pochhammer[a, 5]

(* a (1 + a) (2 + a) (3 + a) (4 + a) *)
```

Do note, the *Mathematica* definition by default is opposite that used in many fields: it is the *Rising Factorial*, while the traditional form can be confused with *Falling Factorial*, the perhaps more common use of *Pochhammer*...

Comment: @2012rcampion Oops...

Answer (score 1):

You can also construct that series yourself, should you need that in another context in the future:

```
sa[n_]:=Product[a+i,{i,0,n-1}];
```

and insert that into your formula:

```
2 Sum[sa[n]/(n!(2 n+1)^3), {n,0,\[Infinity]}]
```

or avoid the function and write:

```
2 Sum[Product[a+i,{i,0,n-1}]/(n!(2 n+1)^3), {n,0,\[Infinity]}]
```

both giving you the result:

```
(1/(16 Gamma[3/2-a]))Sqrt[\[Pi]]
  Gamma[1-a] (\[Pi]^2+2 PolyGamma[0,1/2]^2 - 
   4 PolyGamma[0,1/2] PolyGamma[0,3/2-a] + 
   2 PolyGamma[0,3/2-a]^2 - 2 PolyGamma[1,3/2-a])
```